# Row Level Formula With Picklist

Tags: formula, custom-reports

I am trying to say if campaign names are equal to certain names, then change from registered to attended, otherwise just put the results of the field. The issue is that the field is a picklist so getting that error. This is what I have so far.

```
IF(OR(Campaign.Name == "Virtual Summer Camp Session #1", Campaign.Name == "Virtual Summer Camp Session#2"),
ISPICKVAL(CampaignMember_ContactOrLead.Camper_Status__c,"Registered"),
ISPICKVAL(CampaignMember_ContactOrLead.Camper_S,
)
```

Not sure what to put for the else part of the if statement.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hey, I want the else statement to say just list the results of the field. But since the field is a picklist getting the error "Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions." I need to be able to say if the capaign names are these two then change the camper status field from registered to attended but if not then just list the field as is. The issue is that the field is a picklist so i dont know how to write it.